# What qualities does Hong Kong Mandarin have?

Tags: mandarin, topolect, hong-kong

With Mandarin making more and more in-roads into Cantonese speaking Hong Kong, I'm wondering what characteristics set it apart from Standard Mandarin or other regional Mandarin dialects and/or accents.

I'm not asking so much about native Mandarin speakers that have relocated to Hong Kong. But about Hong Kongers whose first language is Cantonese but also speak fluent Mandarin.

When a Mandarin speaker visits Hong Kong what stands out most?

Other areas where Mandarin is spoken with identifiable regional differences have Wikipedia articles, but Hong Kong does not. Compare the articles on Mandarin in [Singapore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singaporean_Mandarin) and [Taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwanese_Mandarin) for instance.

(If it is felt that this question would fit in better at linguistics.SE I am not opposed to migrating it there.)

Comment: There's definitely sometimes a slight different in pronunciation. For instance, Leung Chunying seems to somtimes have "bad" pronunciation compared to "standard" Mandarin, and from what I've seen, this is something that isn't uncommon among native speakers of Cantonese.

Comment: I don't know how anyone can answer this question. Hong Kong people speak Mandarin with a Cantonese accent. Easier if you can hear it for yourself. Too troublesome to describe in writing though examples can be given with an idea of how they would pronounce it differently from the standard pronunciation.

Comment: Yeah, honestly as far as I can tell, the sort of Mandarin spoken by people in Hong Kong is more or less similar to those spoken by other Cantonese speakers in terms of accent...

Comment: I don't know anyone who can answer most of the questions on this site. But thanks to Stack Exchange there are sites where many experts who I do not know congregate and some of those have the answers to questions I am pondering. For easy questions I do not need such a site.

Comment: Canadian comedian Russell Peters gives a good example of how Mandarin vs. Cantonese sounds. This is also a good example of what you can expect Mandarin to sound like when spoken by a Cantonese native. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jL8hV-zjJ_4

Comment: @hungerartist: You seem to assume anyone wondering about Hong Kong Mandarin must be familiar with the Mandarin of other Cantonese speakers. I can amend the question to cover all Cantonese speakers but I'm not sure it would be better that way.

Comment: @hippietrail - I wrote that more of as a general comment on issues with pronunciation (since I don't have the time right now to write up any sort of answer). I was mostly alluding to mispronunciation of Mandarin due to different pronunciation of the same words in Cantonese - something which seems to happen with Cantonese speakers at times.

Comment: @hungerartist: Sorry, I've just noticed what seems to be an odd trend on the site of contributors to make posts along the lines of "I'm not interested in your question." / "Your curiosity is misplaced, just be satisfied with Standard Mandarin.", etc type things. I hope it's not a real trend.

Comment: Pang Ho-cheung speaking Mandarin http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZXo-b9e-f0

Comment: Rather than migrate this question to linguistics.SE I'm going to ask it there too. Here's a link in case anybody here is interested in how the responses compare: [What qualities does Hong Kong Mandarin have?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6556)

Comment: OK, thanks. Will keep an eye on that. I can learn from how they answer it.

Comment: We call it 港台腔. by the way.

Comment: @user3685: Really? I can see the first two characters are like "HKTW" but what is "腔" (qiāng, ㄑㄧㄤ)?

Comment: Since nobody has taken any interest in the question on linguistics.SE I've gone ahead and reworded it to focus on Hong Kong Mandarin vs southern Mandarin generally.

Answer (score 10):

*I am hardly an expert on this topic. I know basically nothing about Cantonese-influenced Mandarin* **per se**, *but I'll offer an answer of the variety that I think hippietrail is looking for. Hopefully other people will be like "I now understand what a good answer to this question is supposed to look like, and furthermore, I know more than that idiot Stumpy Joe Pete! I'll answer it!".*

As I mentioned in [an answer to a similar question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2244/788), most southern Mandarin has the characteristic of merging `zh` `ch` `sh` into the `z` `c` `s` series (e.g., "zhi" pronounced as "zi"). Cantonese does this, so I expect HK Mandarin accents to do so.

In Cantonese (among the many many other differences in pronunciation) the `g` and `k` are preserved in places where, in Mandarin, they have been palatalized into `j` and `q`. For example, 北京 is pronounced "bak1 ging1". (Aside: this helps to explain the outdated Western spellings of "Beijing" as "Peking" and "Chongqing" as "Chungking"--the `q`s and `j`s were originally velar! As for the p/b k/g thing... blame the Europeans.) Sometimes this shows through in people's Mandarin. For instance, some HK classmates of mine mistakenly guessed the pronunciation of 季节 as "gui4jie2" (instead of "ji4jie2").

It's not only `k`s and `g`s that became `j` and `q`. There were also fricatives and affricates that palatalized in similar circumstances (before [i]/[j]). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Chinese_phonology#From_Late_Middle_Chinese_to_Standard_Mandarin) and look for the /tɕ/ /tɕʰ/ /ɕ/ parts.

Possibly related to that: I once had a very young student with a rather hilarious Mandarin accent (I don't know if she was a Canto speaker). In at least some circumstances, `zhi` would become `ji`, `chi` would become `qi`, and `shi` would become `xi`. This culminated in her yelling about a spider:

> 老师，老师，有蜘蛛啊！
>
> Standard: lao3shi1, lao3shi1, you3 zhi1zhu1 a!
>
> Her: lao3xi1, lao3xi1, you3 ji1zhu1 a!

I say that it's possibly related, because in Cantonese, 师 = si1 and 蜘 = zi1 (where the i's are actual [i]s! Not like Mandarin!). By analogy to Cantonese words pronounced sik and zik, you would expect the Mandarin to be xi and ji. So, like I said, possibly related.

Comment: I see. Good post! Similar phenomenon with Hokkien speakers (also southern Chinese like Cantonese speakers). They don't distinguish zh/ch/sh from z/c/s. It all sounds like the latter. I don't know if it's out of habit or laziness.

Comment: @amateur It's from influence from their native 方言--if the language you grow up speaking doesn't have a particular sound, chances are you'll have trouble producing it when learning another language (or 方言). For example, most English-language learners have trouble with "th" ([ð] and [θ]) so they merge that sound with something else. E.g., [z] and [s], as in, "I sink zis is it", or [d] and [f], as in "I fink dis is it". It's not a personality trait like laziness or something.

Comment: Forgot to say Taiwan as an example, they already study Mandarin in school but still don't bother to pronounce zh/ch/sh when talking to each other. I say lazy because ex. 什么 becomes "so mo". Also "sheng" becomes "sen" (no h sound, and no g). Oh! And a popular one is 十 and 四 both sound "si" so 十四 and 四十 are "si si" (no idea if 14 or 40!)

Comment: Even if they don't speak Hokkien, this is how Taiwan Mandarin is generally spoken from my observation. Maybe Hokkien influenced the way Mandarin is spoken in a informal setting even among non-Hokkien speakers.

Comment: @amateur You're saying that if you learn a language in school, and your pronunciation is not perfectly standard, then you're lazy? Should I tell my Chinese coworkers how lazy they are for not pronouncing "th"s as [ð] and [θ]? Maybe I should tell all Americans what lazy bums they are for speaking English with a weird, non-British accent! ...but seriously, I think "lazy" is really, really bad choice of words to describe the phonology of a particular accent or dialect.

Comment: Cantonese merges the initial consonants of some q- and ch- characters in mandarin, for instance, 窗 and 枪 are homophones in Cantonese. There is a joke saying that a Cantonese was on a train in mainland China. He felt hot and wanted to open the window, so he asked the passenger besides him: "你动不动? 不动我就开枪了". (He meant to say 你冻不冻, 不冻我就开窗了)

Comment: @user58955 Great! That's useful information, and it's also a funny joke :)

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: "the `q`s and `j`s were originally palatal!" -- you mean they were originally velar.

Comment: @Claw Good catch. FYI, for things like that, you can directly edit answers.

Comment: Regarding laziness, I think "relaxed" is a better word when talking about pronunciation. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll give my attempt at an answer. I don't have quite the time to give a long list of examples that I see as common qualities, but I can try to add some more in later if necessary.

As mentioned by Stumpy Joe Pete, the `zh`, `ch`, `sh` sounds will sometimes be pronounced as `z`, `c`, or `s`. This may possibly be more prominent in words that sound similar in Mandarin. For instance, a speaker may pronounce the 沙 in 沙田 as `sa1` rather than as `sha1`, which essentially is the Cantonese pronunciation of 沙.

More generally, Hong Kong speakers in particular may be prone to mispronunciation of standard Mandarin (compared to those in 廣東) - the above is a part of this issue. Part of this is probably simply that Mandarin is used less in Hong Kong, outside of school settings or interactions with mainland Chinese. This generally tends to "materialize" by way of Hong Kong speakers pronouncing words/characters more similar to how they might in Cantonese, even when speaking in Mandarin. Anecdotally, two examples of this would be [李家仁's 小明上廣州 song in Mandarin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0RJGAlQAxM), where (as one example) 上 is pronounced to sound more like the Cantonese `soeng5` than the Mandarin `shang4`, or [崔世安's infamous instances of mispronouncing Mandarin in public](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwOemRiuO5A). The latter is (or was?) the chief executive of Macau, but I believe his Mandarin provides a fairly good illustration of how Hong Kong speakers of Mandarin might use pronunciations of words closer to Cantonese pronunciations than the "correct" ones in Mandarin.

Answer (score 3):

In Cantonese, N and L are often mutually mixable.  For example, nian2 年 could be like nien or lien.  So when a Canto speakers tries to say it, it could be like nlian2.
Another classic example is 你 which may be nei or lei.
Even more classic is when someone is from 湖南 and we hear they are from 荷兰 but perhaps linguistically HuNan Hua and Canto are similar mixing their Ns and Ls.

Some cheats for tones like Second tone in Mandarin nearly always is 4th tone (lowest) in Cantonese like 平 or 层. But of course there are tone sandhis like for 楼 (I read that in a [book by Kataoka and Lee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/962279260X)).